# Coefficient shortcut

Tags: polynomials, boolean-algebra, multinomial-coefficients

I'm taking the product of a specific set of polynomials of idempotent variables and want to find a shortcut for counting groups of homogeneous coefficients without performing all the calculations.

The polynomials in question are laid out in this question [Properties of this algebra with idempotent expressions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3459497/properties-of-this-algebra-with-idempotent-expressions)

An example: $(x_1+x_2-x_1x_2)(x_3+x_4-2x_3x_4)$ expands out to give:

$x_1x_3+x_1x_4-2x_1x_3x_4 + x_2x_3+x_2x_4-2x_2x_3x_4 - x_1x_2x_3 - x_1x_2x_4 + 2x_1x_2x_3x_4$

If I then group the terms by homogeneity I get:

$(x_1x_3 + x_1 x_4 + x_2x_3 + x_2 x_4) + (-x_1x_2x_3-x_1x_2x_4-2x_1x_3x_4-2x_2x_3x_4) + (2x_1x_2x_3x_4)$

I am interested in the sums of these coefficients. So for $2$ variables, the sum is $4$, for $3$ variables the sum is $-6$ and for 4 variables the sum is $2$.

So in summary I want a way to go from  $(x_1+x_2-x_1x_2)(x_3+x_4-2x_3x_4) \mapsto \pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ 4 \\ -6 \\ 2}$

I know that the product of the sum of the coefficients in the factors is equal to the sum of the coefficients in the product:
e.g. $(2x+3)(3x+4) = 6x + 17x + 12$

$(2+3)(3+4) = 6+17+12$

but I can't see how I can use this, or if it is even possible. I've also considered that multi-nomial coefficients may come into it, but again couldn't see how.

Another example to highlight the idempotency.

$(x_1+x_2-x_1x_2)(x_2-x_2x_3)$ becomes

$x_1x_2 + x_2 -x_1x_2 -x_1x_2x_3 - x_2x_3 +x_1x_2x_3$

Which simplifies to $x_2 - x_2x_3$ yielding $\pmatrix{ 0 \\ 1 \\ -1\\ 0}$

Answer (score 1):

First, setting all variables to $0$ gives you the constant term.

Now proceed inductively: assume that you know the first $k$ terms (i.e. up to the homogeneous part of degree $k-1$) and call $P_k$ the polynomial truncated to the first $k$ terms. $P_k$ is a polynomial in one variable, where the coefficients are your sums. Set all variables to be equal to $\varepsilon$, divide the whole thing by $\varepsilon^k$, subtract $\frac{P_k(\varepsilon)}{\varepsilon^k}$, and have $\varepsilon$ tend to $0$. The limit is the next sum.

In your example: $(x_1+x_2-x_1x_2)(x_3+x_4-2x_3x_4)$ assume that you know that there are no parts of degree $0$ or $1$, and that the sum of degree $2$ is $4$. Then $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\left(\frac{(2\varepsilon-\varepsilon^2)(2\varepsilon-2\varepsilon^2)}{\varepsilon^3}-\frac{4\varepsilon^2}{\varepsilon^3}\right)=-6$$ is your next term.

Comment: would this run in polynomial time?

Comment: @BenCrossley I don't know how you evaluate the complexity of computing a limit, but my guess is that it's not that bad.

Comment: I'm still trying to wrap my head around how this works. If I can make sense of it I will upvote and accept.

Comment: @BenCrossley Look at what your polynomial becomes when you replace every variable by $\varepsilon$: $4\varepsilon^2-6\varepsilon^3+2\varepsilon^4$. That's essentially your list of coefficients. To get the $\varepsilon^3$ part, delete the previous ones, divide by $\varepsilon^3$, and have $\varepsilon$ tend to $0$.

Comment: I don't think this method will work with my polynomials due to the idempotency. $x_1 x_2 \times x_2 x_3 = x_1x_2x_3$ whereas substituting in $\epsilon$ would give $\epsilon^2 \times \epsilon^2 = \epsilon^4$

Comment: @BenCrossley Oh! Right, I missed that part. But it would be more clear if your worked example featured this. Right now it's just one word buried at the beginning of the introduction.